# A new notion of probability coupling

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control, it.information-theory

Let  $X$ and $Y$ be two discrete random variables distributed according to $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively. Consider the following optimization problems
$$\inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu, \nu)}\Pr(X\neq Y),$$
where $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ denotes the set of all couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$, i.e., all joint distributions $P_{XY}$ whose marginals are given by $\mu$ and $\nu$.

It is very well-known that the above minimization is given by total variation distance:
$$\inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu, \nu)}\Pr(X\neq Y) = d_{TV}(\mu, \nu).$$

My question is s follows. Now consider $X\sim \mu$ and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are two independent samples of $\nu$. Now, what is
$$\inf_{\pi\in \Pi(\mu, \nu)}\Pr(X\neq Y_1, X\neq Y_2)?$$

Has it appeared before? Any connections with known probability distance measures?

Comment: Did you mean $\pi(X \ne Y)$ rather than $\operatorname{Pr}(X \ne Y)$? Also, what is the joint distribution of $(X,Y_1,Y_2)$ once $\pi$ is chosen? (If $\mu=\nu$ and $\pi$ is the diagonal coupling, and both $(X,Y_1)$ and $(X,Y_2)$ are assumed to be distributed according to $\pi$, then we have $X=Y_1$ a.s. and $X=Y_2$ a.s., so it is problematic to require that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent.)

Comment: Yes, I mean $\pi(X\neq Y)$. The joint distribution is given by $\pi(x, y_1, y_2) = \nu(y_1)\nu(y_2)P_{X|Y_1Y_2}(x|y_1,y_2)$ for some conditional distribution $P_{X|Y_1Y_2}$. Then the first marginal should be $\mu$, the second and third should be $\nu$.

Comment: If $\mu = \nu$, then the above infiumum should be zero.

Comment: But look: the infimum is over couplings $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$, while under the infimum a triple coupling $\bar\pi$ of $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\nu$ is used. My point is that for a general $\pi$ it is not possible to construct any $\bar\pi$ such that $\pi(A \times B) = \bar\pi(A \times B \times \mathcal Y) = \bar\pi(A \times \mathcal Y \times B)$ and $\bar\pi(\mathcal X \times B_1 \times B_2) = \nu(B_1)\nu(B_2)$. (Here of course $\mathcal X$ is the set of all possible outcomes of $X$, and $\mathcal Y$ the set of all outcomes of $Y$.)

Comment: I see your point! Maybe the way it's written is not clear!
The  question is this: given two marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$, what is minimum value of $\Pr(X\neq Y_1, X\neq Y_2)$  where $P_{X.Y_1, Y_2}(x, y_1, y_2) = \nu(y_1)\nu(y_2)P_{X|Y_1Y_2}(x|y_1,y_2)$?

Comment: Note that this quantity can vanish even if $\mu \neq \nu$,  for example when $\mu$ is the law of $\min\{Y_1,Y_2\}$, so it wouldn't be a good notion of 'distance'...

Comment: It's a very nice observation! But I expected it...I think it'll be a certain type of $f$-divergence [which is not strictly convex at 1, and thus it being equal to zero does not necessarily imply $\mu = \nu$].